# Multiple entry points to a storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, point

I need to make a set of decisions in the AppDelegate on launch - depending on the outcome of those decisions I need to go to specific parts of the storyboard.

So my question is - WITHOUT using any nav or tab controllers, how do I go to a specific part of a storyboard?

OR

Is the only supported option having multiple storyboards - for each of the 'outcomes' and then loading those as required?

Thanks

Comment: Probably was but I didn't find it with the search I did before posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give each of your ViewControllers a separate ID, and then instantiate the required one with:

```
UIViewController *initialVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<identifier>"];
```

Comment: Thank you for replying...

I actually worked out what I wanted to do:

In the app delegate when the decision is made I get the storyboard, then the view controller like in your example and then I set the self.window.rootviewcontroller to that new view controller.

Otherwise if it doesn't pass the decision tests, then I just let it default to the main storyboard.

To move from one storyboard to another I've been using the instantiateView with the completion handler, where I then remove that view the did the push from it's superview.

Answer (score 11):

Give each ViewController a unique identifier in the storyboard.
Then in the appDelegate:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PUT_UNIQUE_ID_HERE"];
    //DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH YOUR VIEWCONTROLLER
   //Example:Set it as the root view of the app window...
```