# Setting an identifier for an Xcode Storyboard Segue in a UITabBarController, and getting a pointer to its view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

This is my first app using storyboards/segues, and I'm pretty sure the answer to this is easy, but I'll be as thorough as possible in describing my issue.

I am making a simple app which has a Tab Bar Controller scene and two View Controllers.

[image: View of my Storyboard, with one of the "Relationships" highlighted]

My app launches by being sent a URL from another app.  The `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method in the app delegate performs some work to determine

- which tab to display first, and
- what information to display on it.

My goal is to use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method (I'm open to alternatives though) from within the *AppDelegate* to select the tab, and also find a way to send a method to the instance of the view controller created by the storyboard.

**Issue #1** is that I can't set an identifier.  When I select the tab "relationship" there are no choices available in the Attributes Inspector (it says "Not Applicable").  How do I set a name for this segue?  Can I?  Or is there some rule under which *UITabBarController* segues can't be trigger programmatically?

**Issue #2** is that I can't find a way to have a pointer to the view controller.  Pre-Storyboard I would `alloc` and `init` a new view controller and then set it up, but here if I do that, it does not get displayed when my app launches (I think this is because Storyboard is displaying a different instance of the same view controller.)

I know this post is long, but I feel like I'm missing something simple.  What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to have your AppDelegate [set the entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872215/multiple-entry-points-to-a-storyboard) to your storybard.

Comment: That question suggests using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.  This creates a new instance of the view controller, so changes I make to it (such as setting text on UILabels, for example) don't appear when the app is launched.  Unless I set the view controller to the "root" view controller, in which case the TabBar no longer appears.